# Monitor when read/write on metadata or mmaped files hit the disk

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, monitoring, io, cgroups

On a server hosting a wide range of websites, I often see IO becoming a bottleneck without being able to identify the processes responsible of IO operations with tools such as iotop, iostat or sar.

I suspect that those processes are performing a lot of IO on metadata (reading and/or writing attributes, creating or removing a lot of empty files, etc). Unfortunately, it seems that those operations are not accounted "per processes", nor are IO performed using memory-mapped files (mmap).

My question is: Is there a way to monitor and/or account (for instance, using cgroups and blkio) IO per process or (maybe even better) per file, including io on metadata and memory-mapped files?

Currently, I'm trying to account "which requests hit the disk" using systemtap, probing handle_mm_fault() (mm/memory.c in the kernel) for major page faults, but I haven't been able to verify if manipulation of filesystem metadata generates page faults handled by this function.

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: I guess you have already checked but what is the swapping usage like in vmstat? Also, do you have a DBMS running and what IO scheduler do you?

Comment: There is no DBMS, just a webserver, but it is worth noting that the server is also an nfs server that can be highly solicited.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot, there is no swap partition on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a systemtap script which is close to what I wanted to do, but it does not track writes.

The code is on a gist: https://gist.github.com/Martiusweb/10633360

Comment: That's pretty good. Add some system() calls to rrdtool and you would have a pretty mean metric and graphical representation too.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment I have just remembered this great command : **iotop**

```
iotop  watches I/O usage information output by the Linux kernel (requires
2.6.20 or later) and displays a table of current I/O usage by processes or 
threads on the system.
```

However it is usually not installed so since your server seems to be in production, you may want to have a look [here](http://bencane.com/2012/08/06/troubleshooting-high-io-wait-in-linux/) if you can t install it.

Also **lsof** is a great command to check files opened by process.

Comment: If you still can't find why and you are using a DBMS, read this :http://engineering.linkedin.com/performance/optimizing-linux-memory-management-low-latency-high-throughput-databases

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already use iotop and it seems that it doesn't give me enough information (Global read/write troughput is greater than the sum of what is accounted per process).